# Q: Does anyone use service accounts?

Tags: account

We're in the process of switching our security model to include the use of service accounts. Unfortunately, in the past we had an administrator put all of these accounts in his name. When he left, we had a hayday trying to track down every place he used his account for our external applications.

We'd like to create an account for each Salesforce application we utilize. My question is, does Salesforce allow a free or discounted user license for these type of accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not at all uncommon to create "Integration User", "API User", and similar accounts. In fact, it's frequently a very good idea to have them. To answer your question, Salesforce does not provide for "free" or discounted user licenses for these types of User Accounts.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it never hurts to ask :) Thanks for your help